# Get values from from multiple select[multiple] with the same class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the values of selected options from a couple of different `<select multiple='multiple'>` on my page. These picklists have the same class(food) so I would like to use that in order to reference them all. This is my code so far.

```
var checkedVals = $('.food :selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

And here is what one of my selects looks like all rendered out.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_form-0-foods" class="food" name="form-0-foods">
<option value="1">meat</option>
<option value="2">fish</option>
<option value="3">bread</option>
<option value="4">cheese</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: more details below.

The above jquery snippet is wrapped in this:

```
$("option").live('dblclick', function () {

});
```

Also, im using django formsets and http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/05/14/reuse-djangos-filter_horizontal-admin-widget.html

NEW EDIT: The issue was that the Django admin widget that I was using sets the options to selected in "view source" but when I inspected individual elements, there was no such thing going on in the code. I was getting empty lists and this was what was supposed to happen.

Comment: Did you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119015/how-to-get-the-multiple-values-of-a-select-box?rq=1 ?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/WujAt/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/M8Aga/

Comment: @roasted & SachinG - only an empty list is logged into my console

Comment: Not in my console under chrome

Comment: Sorry my bad, no errors and the fiddles are working fine in Chrome. No dice when I move the code over to my own project though.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine for me.  One thing that may be a problem is the double click, as that would select and then unselect the items.

http://plunker.co/edit/UGGJ1U4lf2uSckdZyeqG?p=preview